# Very slow file upload in Rails on localhost

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, file-upload

I using carrierwave and jQuery file upload. I trying upload files on localhost. Rails benchmark says that total time is few mseconds:

[image]

But in all browsers this time grow up to unbelievable values!
Here is example from chrome:

[image]

File size is ~1MB

Comment: All time spent in the browser/javscript.  What type of file are you uploading?  What does your jQuery code look like?  Check out https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/issues/1450 if applicable.

Comment: Type doesn't matter. There are images, pdf, txt, etc. jQuery code I got from example. I think, it's not jquery problem. Because when rails end his work and upload file in "pending" state, ruby proccess eats all my CPU while pending status go away. More file size - more time for upload in abnormal scale.

Comment: did you look at the lines ```Completed 406 Not Acceptable``` ? is your jquery handling this answer correctly?

Comment: I'm having similar problem. After file has been uploaded to server Rails eats up 100% CPU and takes many seconds to respond.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a middleware and just insert it before Rack, such as:

```
class MultipartBufferSetter

  def initialize(app)
    @app = app
  end

  def call(env)
    env.merge!(Rack::RACK_MULTIPART_BUFFER_SIZE => 100*1024*1024)
    @app.call(env)
  end

end
```

and then:

```
config.middleware.insert_before "Rack::Runtime", "MultipartBufferSetter"
```

You can find more info [here](https://github.com/rack/rack/issues/1075)

Hope it works